# How do I keep an npm idle-session-timeout consistent across webapp?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I'm using the idle-session-timeout module from https://www.npmjs.com/package/idle-session-timeout

I need to keep the session consistent in order to destroy it on whatever thread it needs to be destroyed.

`if (authState.state == 'signedIn'){
          var session;
          var timeOutLength = (60 * 1 * 1000);
          var dateTime = localStorage.getItem('sessionTime');`

I have tried creating the session variable outside of the method and only starting it here, but it doesn't seem to work at all that way.

Manually disposing the session works but it isn't destroyed on timeout when I call the same method that destroys it manually.

Comment: It now destroys the session when it times out but not when i manually try dispose of it

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was creating the event methods inside of the case that the session was created, I needed to define those methods regardless of whether or not the session would end up being created.